# Puppet to Chef Syntax Convertion

Tags: chef-infra, puppet

I'll have to convert a lot of Puppet to Chef code.
I made some Chef tutorials and I'll be reading about Puppet too.

Does anybody know where I can find more examples of comparisons between Puppet and Chef code?
(Like this Puppet code would look like this in Chef code)

Perfect would be a full on guide which helps me to convert the code.

The ones I have found only had about 3 Examples...

best wishes
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/search?q=puppet+chef+rosetta will show you many options. Overall, it's not quite a one-to-one due to the different styles at work.

Comment: Thanks! Well I found one more example code so that's good. Maybe even a project (like on Github) which is written in puppet and chef would also help...